# How can I validate a regular expression using jQuery Validation plugin?

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate

How can I validate a regular expression using jQuery Validation plugin? In this code we can validate the form using one jQuery plugin, "jQuery Validation" plugin but I don't know to validate regular expression by using this plugin.

```
 <!DOCtype html>
   <html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<body>
<form method="post" name="signup_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table>
<tr><td>First Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First name" required><span> *</span></td></tr>
<tr><td>Middle Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="middle_name" placeholder="Middle Name"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Last Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" required><span> *</span></td></tr>
<tr><td>Username:</td><td><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required><span> *</span></td></tr>
<tr><td>Password:</td><td><input id="password1" type = "password" name="password" required/><span> *</span></td></tr>
<tr><td>Re-Enter Password:</td><td><input class="left" id="password_again" type = "password"  name="password_again" required/><span> *</span></td></tr>
<tr><td>Email:</td><td> <input id="email" type="email" name="email" required/><span> *</span></td></tr>
<tr><td>Gender:</td><td><input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" required>Male <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" required> Female<span> *</span></td></tr>
<tr><td>Date of Birth:</td><td><select name = "day" required><option value="">Day</option>
<?php for($i = 1; $i < 32; $i++){?>
<option value = "<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?></option>
<?php }?>
</select>
<select name="month" required><option value="">Month</option>

<option value = "jan">Jan</option>
<option value = "feb">Feb</option>
<option value = "mar">Mar</option>
<option value = "apr">Apr</option>
<option value = "may">May</option>
<option value = "jun">Jun</option>
<option value = "jul">Jul</option>
<option value = "aug">Aug</option>
<option value = "sep">Sep</option>
<option value = "oct">Oct</option>
<option value = "nov">Nov</option>
<option value = "dec">Dec</option>

</select>
<select name = "year" required><option value="">Year</option>
<?php for($i = 2013; $i > 1904; $i--){?>
<option value = "<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?></option>
<?php }?>
</select><span> *</span></td></tr>
<tr><td>Address Line 1:</td><td><input type="text" name="address1" placeholder="Address Line 1" required><span> *</span></td></tr>
<tr><td>Address Line 2:</td><td><input type="text" name="address2" placeholder="Address Line 2"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Country:</td><td><input type="text" name="country" placeholder="Country" required><span> *</span></td></tr>
<tr><td>State:</td><td><input type="text" name="state" placeholder="State" required><span> *</span></td></tr>
<tr><td>City:</td><td><input type="text" name="city" placeholder="City" required><span> *</span></td></tr>
<tr><td>Pincode:</td><td><input type="text" name="pincode" placeholder="Pincode" required><span> *</span></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" align="center">
<input type="submit" value="Enter" formaction="sucess.php"></td></tr>
</table>
<script >


$("#signup_form" ).validate();</script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/).

Comment: By finding a plugin, passing it your input, then assessing the result :)

Comment: Can you mention one good plugin?

Comment: @sanu That was a joke. You don't need jQuery nor any plugin to validate a regular expression.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need for jQuery. Use the RegExp constructor and catch the exception :

```
try {
    new RegExp(someString);
    console.log('good'); 
} catch (e) {
    console.log('bad'); 
}
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/ixEreSi/1/) (type something in the input to know if it's a well formed regular expression)

Comment: Oh come on, you could have at least made that jQuery plugin :D

Comment: @hakre in my demo I use jQuery :)

Answer (score 3):

> Title: How can I validate a regular expresion using jQuery Validation plugin?

**Simply answering the question that was presented...**

---

**Quote OP:**

> *"... we can validate the form using one jquery plugin, "jQuery Validation" Plugin but I don't know to validate regular expression by using this plugin."*

Firstly, you do not need to include both the un-minified and minified versions of the jQuery Validate plugin.  Choose one or the other.  In this example, minified...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
```

---

You can simply use the `pattern` rule to validate a regular expression.  Include the `additional-methods.js` file and declare your regex as the parameter.

```
    rules: {
        field1: {
            required: true,
            pattern: '[a-zA-Z]+'
        },
        ....
```

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/36tegu4o/**

---

Since you are targeting your form with jQuery by `$("#signup_form")`, it will not work because there is no `id="signup_form"` within your `<form>` tag.  You'll need to add this `id`...

```
<form name="signup_form" id="signup_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

*Otherwise*, if you can't add the `id`, you'll need to change the jQuery selector to target the `name` instead...

```
$("form[name='signup_form']").validate({ ...
```

---

Alternatively, create your custom method/rule using [the `addMethod` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/).  In this case, I call it `myCustomMethod`...

```
$.validator.addMethod("myCustomMethod", function(value, element) {
    // your javascript regex function
    // return true if it passes
    // return false if it fails and the message will automatically display
}, "your custom error message");
```

Then call [`.validate()`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) to initialize the plugin and assign your rules.  `myFieldName` represents the `name` attribute of the field where you want the rule assigned.  Your jQuery should be enclosed in a DOM ready event handler to ensure the HTML is fully constructed before the DOM is manipulated...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#signup_form").validate({
        rules: {
            myFieldName: {
                myCustomMethod: true
            }
        }
    });  // close validate()

});  // close document.ready
```

**DEMO**:  http://jsfiddle.net/HVtCy/

---